# How to find the dimension of a representation?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $V$ be an $n$ dimensional complex vector space. Let $\rho$ be the representation such that $\rho(g)v=v\,\forall v\in V , \forall g\in G.$ Then what is the dimension of this representation $\rho$?

Comment: The dimension of a representation $\rho\colon G\to GL(V)$ is by definition the dimension of the representation space $V$.

Comment: That means dimension of this representation is $n$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The particular action of $\rho$ is not needed to know the dimension here.

Comment: While Ben has given you the answer, a useful observation is that the identity map on an n dimensional space has trace n, and so the dimension of a representation can be recovered from the character, as it is $\operatorname{tr}(\rho(e))$ where $e$ is the identity element of $G$.  This goes to show that finding the dimension of a representation is dependent on what information about the representation you have.